# Deleting Data Extension after Journey Complete

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a 1 Month Journey and as per business need, after completing 1 month Journey every single subscriber needs to move from Source DE to some other DE.

I was thinking to make Data Retention Policy for 1 month. But it will delete record from that DE. So it will not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You use SQL Query to copy the subscribers from the Source DE to a new one after completing the Journey (manually).

Comment: Just to ensure there is no confusion, subscribers do NOT need to stay in the entry source DE once they have been injected in a journey

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to have a copy of your Source DE and then use a SQL Query to do a full copy of that DE to your copy DE.

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM [sourceDE]

/* Target: copyDE */
/* Action: Update */
```

You then would run a second SQL query to overwrite your Source DE to 'clear' it of all the info:

```
SELECT *
FROM [copyDE]
WHERE 1 = 2

/* Target: SourceDE */
/* Action: Overwrite */
```

by setting the condition 1 = 2, you will guarantee a return of 0, which means that the overwrite will delete all records and add in the results (none) from your query - therefore a duct tape 'clear' of sorts.

This will allow you to keep a sort of archive of your Journey data in the copyDE without bogging down your SourceDE.

One thing of note though is that any emails sent may have issues with the VAWP if deleted from the Source DE.  I am not sure, since they are going through JB, if this is applicable (I believe the VAWP is based off Journey Data, not Contact Data, so it is stored temporarily outside the DE itself.)

Comment: why not combine the data copy sql to move records with a record based data retention approach? With that you would not need the 'duct tape' clear. It would be easier to manage and is closer to standard functionality

Comment: yeah, but if there is an error with the query and it doesn't copy, the retention will still clear it and then you lose that data. By only letting the clear run after the data is moved, then you make sure to remove risk of data loss

Comment: That is something to consider for sure. With the mentioned retention period of 1 month error management should be easily possible. For anything under 1 week I would prefer your way.

Comment: I am a bit of a control freak with data. I would rather have the ability to manually turn it off in case of emergency or manually run it if needed. It is all subjective though, a 1 month retention period would work just as well too if you prefer.